# Eu devo criar um form para cada linha/registro dessa datatable?

Tags: html

Em uma situação hipotética com um `datatable`, de forma assíncrona será feito um `swith` de `ativo/inativo` para o registro.

Eu devo criar um [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) para cada linha/registro dessa datatable? É semanticamente incorreto? Ou devo manipular os dados através de `ids`, `data attributes`, etc... ?

Exemplificando essa situação, seria algo  como:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>
      <td>Nome</td>
      <td>Ativo</td>
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <form id="1">
      <tr>
        <td>Fulano</td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="ativo">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </form>

    <form id="2">
      <tr>
        <td>Cicrano</td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="ativo">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </form>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: que eu saiba você pode criar sua table dentro de um form, não precisa separar tudo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode colocar sua table dentro do formulário e coloque o `name` dos `checkbox` com nomes diferentes, não sei como você vai usar esse formulário depois, mas o certo é identificá-las com nomes diferentes, espero que isso te ajude não sei se é realmente isso que precisa:

```
<form id="formulario">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>
          <td>Nome</td>
          <td>Ativo</td>
        </th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Fulano</td>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" name="ativo1">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cicrano</td>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" name="ativo2">
            </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```